# Is the vacuum state in superposition before measurement of its gravity effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, vacuum, superposition

In the case of a particle system the wave function or state vector is in a superposition of possibilities before measurement.

But does this rule apply in the case of vacuum state?

Is it in a superposition of (energy) possibilities before measurement?

We might say that nothing is there to measure in the vacuum. In particular virtual particles in the vacuum are non observable by definition.

But with gravity, the effect of vacuum on curvature, can be measured and we can get information about it.

Does "before measurement" make sense here at all?